# Pulling Information From a Stock Screener

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am new at using selenium to scrape information. I want to scrape prices in the Bid and Ask section. When I inspected the webpage source, I found that it is run by a JavaScript.
This is what I have tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# specify the url
urlpage = 'https://banggia.vps.com.vn/chung-khoan/derivative-VN30'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(urlpage)
# print(driver.page_source)
# root = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
# print(root)
WebDriverWait(driver, 
10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"ptifrmtgtframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
"//span[@id='root']")))
# //*[@id="root"]/div/div[5]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[9]/span[1]
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

However, I received an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/quank/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.2/scratches/scratch.py", line 17, 
in <module>
WebDriverWait(driver, 
10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"ptifrmtgtframe")))
File "C:\Users\quank\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Here is the link the website: [https://banggia.vps.com.vn/chung-khoan/derivative-VN30][1].
Again, I am new at using selenium and trying to learn new things because I haven't learned about web-scraping at my school. Therefore, please add some explanations on your answer so that I can learn how to scrape website like this one in future. I appreciate any helps and thanks in advance.

Updated: I tried to gather information into an 'Element' list and print it out using a for-loop. However, I only get the name of a class.

```
from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
path = 'C:/Users/quank/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
url = 'https://banggia.vps.com.vn/chung-khoan/derivative-VN30'
driver.get(url=url)
element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#root > div > 
div.content.undefined > div.derivative > table.price-table > tbody')
for i in element:
    print(i.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

And here is the result:

```
<tbody class="price-table-content"></tbody>
```

Any helps to get the content of the "price-table-content" is appreciated :)
[1]: https://banggia.vps.com.vn/chung-khoan/derivative-VN30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 
10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"ptifrmtgtframe")))
```

you are waiting for iframe located by ID= `ptifrmtgtframe`
But there is no such iframe there.
Moreover, there is no any iframe on that page.
This is why Selenium fails finding such element in the timeout of 10 seconds as you defined here and it throws `TimeoutException` exception.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So how can I scrape information on the Bid and Ask tables?